# drawImage() not drawing pre-loaded image object. Using OO javascript

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, drawimage

I'm writing a simple 2D side scroller game using JavaScript + Canvas.  I am trying to do this while learning OO JavaScript.  I'm encountering an issue where my image will not draw to the canvas, despite being loaded correctly.  Here's the code:

```
//===================================
// class - Canvas
//===================================

var classCanvas = function(id){
    canvas  = document.getElementById(id);
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
}

//===================================
// abstract class - Image Drawer
//===================================

var classImageDrawer = function(that){
this.draw = function(){
    context.drawImage(that.img,
                      that.spriteCoordsX,
                      that.spriteCoordsY,
                      that.width,
                      that.height,
                      that.posX,
                      that.posY,
                      that.width,
                      that.height);
    }
}

//===================================
// class - Level
//===================================

var classLevel = function(name, src){
   this.name           = name;
   this.img            = new Image();
   this.img.src        = src;
   this.img.onload     = function(){ };
   this.spriteCoordsX  = 0;
   this.spriteCoordsY  = 0;
   this.posY           = 0;
   this.posX           = 0;
   this.height         = 400;
   this.width          = 600;
   this.drawer         = new classImageDrawer(this);
}

//==================================
//  Begin 
//==================================

var game      = new classCanvas("playground");
game.LevelOne = new classLevel("LevelOne", "images/foreground-land.png");

game.LevelOne.drawer.draw();
```

I have checked the code, and I know the image is getting loaded correctly.  No errors occur during runtime, the image "foreground-land.png" simply DOESN'T show up on the canvas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image may be loading fine, but as far as I can tell your call to `game.LevelOne.drawer.draw()` has no guarantee that `foreground-land.png` has loaded *at that point* (remember, images are loaded asynchronously without blocking the execution of other code).

Your `onload` function for the image object in your `classLevel` class is empty and anonymous. Nothing happens when the image is finished loading. I'm not sure how you want to structure your code given everything else you have going on, but you should only allow the call to `game.LevelOne.drawer.draw()` to succeed if the resources it depends upon have been fully loaded. The best way to do this would be to hook into the `onload` callback for all resources you require for that object (in this case, it's just the one image).

Comment: Here's something else I don't quite understand.  Based on your suggestion, I figured I could test the validity of your theory by using setTimeout.  I did the following:  

     `setTimeout(game.LevelOne.drawer.draw(),5000);`  

I would have thought this would work.  But since setTimeout isn't technically sleeping, maybe its still calling draw() before the image is loaded?

Comment: @user965927 No problem! using `setTimeout()` with a large enough delay should allow you to test things for the time being, but understand that it's a temporary fix. There's no way to know how long the user will spend downloading the image. In your snippet here, `game.LevelOne.drawer.draw()` is actually being called immediately and the return value is then passed to `setTimeout()`. You'll want to put your function call in quotes, instead: `setTimeout("game.LevelOne.drawer.draw()",5000);`

Answer (score 0):

Loading images is an async operation, you are (basically) ignoring the loading process, and acting as though it is sync operations.

One thing you could look at is using a 3rd parameter as a callback ("LevelOne", "images/foreground-land.png", function() { this.drawer.draw() }) and doing that as the onload